# Extract a word from a line of HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

I have the following line from a html file.

```
src=\"https://www.com/seek-images/seek-icons/horoskop-*pluto.gif*\" alt=\"\" />*Pluto*</div>\n
```

Using Python , regex, How do I extract Pluto (or any planet name here)..from the above line.

I tried regex with [\w]+ and

```
match = re.search(regexeg, line)
if match:
        print "begin"
        print match.groups()
        for group in match.groups():
                print ('{} '.format(group))
```

the group is empty. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Obligatory link to warning about [parsing html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup to parse HTML.

Comment: What do you understand ` [\w]+` to mean?

Comment: Does the file really have those backslashes, or were they added by the Ask Question wizard?

Comment: `\w` won't match the `.` character in `pluto.gif`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use beautifulsoup to parse the html.

First install beautiful soup :

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then parse the entire html and extract the text from the div element, something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_line = '<div> <img src="https://www.com/seek-images/seek-icons/horoskop-*pluto.gif*" alt="" />*Pluto*</div>\n'

# Parse the HTML line with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_line, 'html.parser')

# Find the div tag containing the planet name
div_tag = soup.find('div')

if div_tag:
    planet_name = div_tag.get_text(strip=True)
    print("Planet Name:", planet_name)
else:
    print("No div tag found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, thou shalt not parse HTML with regexes.

But if you really need to, here's the simplest version for the string you've shown.

```
>\*([A-z]+)\*<
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/oCquuk/1).

It might very well be not specific enough for the whole HTML document, but for that you really need LXML or BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is always preceding an ending *div* tag, try the following.

```
(?<=/>\*).+?(?=\*</div>)
```

Here is an example.

```py
import re
s = 'src=\"https://www.com/seek-images/seek-icons/horoskop-*pluto.gif*\" alt=\"\" />*Pluto*</div>\n'
p = r'(?<=/>\*).+?(?=\*</div>)'
v = re.search(p, s).group()
```

Output

```
Pluto
```